# How to compare two LTLs?

Tags: automata, formal-verification, model-checking, spin, promela

How can I compare two LTLs to see if one can contradict each other? I ask this because I have a hierarchical state machine and LTLs describing the behavior in each state. I need to know if a local LTL can contradict a global LTL. I saw in the Article 'Feature Specification and Automated Conflict Detection' that two LTLs properties f and g are inconsistent iff L(f) intersection L(g) is empty. And this is exactly the model checking question with f as the program and ¬g as the property. Can anyone help me with this? How can I transform an LTL f into a program in SPIN/Promela??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me. (Warning: I've not seen this in official documentation. This could mean that there are other, better ways to do this. Or that I didn't look hard enough.)

We want to check whether  `[] <> p  &&  [] <> q` implies `<> (p && q)`. (It does not.)

Write a trivial process `P` that can do all transitions, and write the claim as an LTL property `A`.

```
bool p; bool q;

active proctype P () {
  do :: d_step { p = false; q = false } 
     :: d_step { p = false; q = true }  
     :: d_step { p = true; q = false } 
     :: d_step { p = true; q = true }  
  od
}

ltl A { (([] <> p) && ([] <> q)) -> <> (p && q) }
```

(EDIT 1-Nov-2016: this may be incorrect because we might be missing some transitions because of a hidden initial state, see [how to make a non-initialised variable in Spin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358915/how-to-make-a-non-initialised-variable-in-spin)  )

Then put this in a file `check.pml`, and

```
spin -a check.pml
cc     pan.c   -o pan
./pan -a -n
./pan -r check.pml.trail -v
```

shows a model of the negation of the claim (an ultimately periodic trail where `p` and `q` are true infinitely often, but `p && q` is never).

Double-check: change the conclusion in the claim to `<> (p || q)`, then there is no counter-examle, proving that the implication is valid.

In your case, the claim is  `! (f && g)` (they should never be true at the same time).

There probably is some clever way to make the code for the trivial process smaller.

Also, the third command is actually `./pan -a  -i -n` (the `-i` to find a shortest example) but it gives a warning. And it does find a shorter cycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I tested with the claim ([] (p && q)) && (<> !(p)), where f is [] (p && q) and g is <> !(p). For me this two LTLs are contradictory because !p willl contradict [] p.  When I tested SPIN show me  the message: " Error: assertion violated
spin: text of failed assertion: assert(!(!((p&&q))))" and did not show me a counter-example. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line (as I wrote) or in ispin or some other GUI?

Comment: You want to show that your `f` and `g` are contradictory, that is, `f && g` is false for ALL runs of the system. Then you should specify `ltl { ! (f && g) }` and you have proved it if spin finds NO counterexample.

Comment: So, if I want to prove that there is NO contradiction between f and g, thus the ltl { ! (f && g)} always will show me a counterexample? (I'm sorry, I do not have much knowledge on that subject))

Comment: Yes. - "I do not have much knowledge" - then why are you doing this? Is it some kind of homework/assignment? Then talk to the person who assigned it, as they can relate it to your syllabus, etc.

Comment: I need to do this. It is a small part of my Masters. Thanks for all help.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 I can't see how the initialisation part affects your model, could you clarify it?

Comment: I want a system (specified by the Promela program) that realizes the trace language `{ {p=0,q=0},{p=0,q=1},{p=1,q=0},{p=1,q=1} }^omega`, that is, all omega words over the given alphabet (assignments of p and q). With the initialisation, the trace language is `{p=0,q=0} { {p=0,q=0},{p=0,q=1},{p=1,q=0},{p=1,q=1} }^omega`, that is, all words starting with `{p=0,q=0}`. Equivalence on this language may differ from equivalence on the full language.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Yes, of course in general I agree with you, but on this specific example it shouldn't make any difference as far as I understand. So I would rephrase the *"this may be incorrect"* part because it sounds like your specific example might be incorrect, instead of the general case. For what concerns checking the existence of a *"contradiction"* among ltl formulas, I proposed this [other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780330/how-to-transform-ltl-into-automato-in-promela-spin/38806665#38806665) which dodges the model checking part entirely.