# How to transform LTL into Automato in Promela - SPIN?

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

How can I transform LTL into Automata in PROMELA? I know that with the command SPIN -f "ltl x" it is possible transform the LTL into a never claim, but I want  the automata of the LTL and not the negation one. It is correct  If I negate the LTL before to generate the never claim. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would [this](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba) be helpful, or you strictly require a solution based on *spin*?

Comment: Actually I would like a way to transform the LTL into a PROMELA Automata. I think this website transform into a never claim. If a put [](q11 -> !q0) for the transformation, the response is the never claim:


    never { /* G(q11 -> !q0) */
    accept_init :    /* init */
     if
     :: (!q0) || (!q11) -> goto accept_init
     fi;
    }




You think that I can use just the code inside the code snippet Never{}? This is the the Automata for the LTL G(q11 -> !q0).
I appreciate the help.

Comment: yes, the code inside the *never { }* represents the ltl formula / Buchi automaton.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick.

Comment: Just for the records, this question is linked [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484361/how-to-compare-two-ltls?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Spin* generates the *Promela* code equivalent to the *Buchi Automaton* which matches the *LTL formula*, and envelops it into a *never* block.

From the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/never.html):

> **NAME**  never - declaration of a temporal claim.
>
> **SYNTAX**  never { sequence }
>
> **DESCRIPTION**  A never claim can be used to define system behavior that,
>   for whatever reason, is of special interest. It is most commonly used
>   to specify behavior that should never happen. The claim is defined as
>   a series of propositions, or boolean expressions, on the system state
>   that must become true in the sequence specified for the behavior of
>   interest to be matched.

Therefore, **if** you want to have a look at the code that matches a given *LTL formula*, you can simply type:

```
~$ spin -f "LTL_FORMULA"
```

**e.g.:**

```
~$ spin -f "[] (q1 -> ! q0)" 
never  {    /* [] (q1 -> ! q0) */
accept_init:
T0_init:
    do
    :: (((! ((q0))) || (! ((q1))))) -> goto T0_init
    od;
}
```

An alternative way for obtaining the same code, plus a graphic representation of the *Buchi Automaton*, is to [follow this link](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba).

---

Looking at both *your comments* and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484361/how-to-compare-two-ltls?rq=1) question of yours, it appears that you want to check whether two *LTL formulas* **p** and **g** contradict each other, that is whether it is definitively the case that a model *satisfying* **p** would necessarily violate **g** and vice-versa.

This could be *theoretically* done using **spin**. However, this tool does not simplify the code of the *Buchi Automaton* and therefore it is difficult to deal with its output.

I would reccomend you to download **LTL2BA** (at the following [link](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/download.php)) instead. To set it up, you just need to unpack the *tar.gz* file and type *make* in the console.

Let's see a usage example:

```
~$ ./ltl2ba -f "([] q0) && (<> ! q0)"
never {    /* ([] q0) && (<> ! q0) */
T0_init:
    false;
}
```

Since `[] q0` and `<> ! q0` contradict each other, the returned *Buchi automaton* is *empty* [n.b.: by *empty* i mean that it has no accepting execution]. In this context, the code *never { false; }* is the *canonical form* of an *empty* *Buchi Automaton* without any accepting execution.

---

**Disclaimer:** comparing the output with *never { false }* to decide whether the *Buchi Automaton* is empty or not, might lead to *spurious* results if the *simplification* steps are unable to transform all *empty* automatons in the *canonical form*.

Comment: Thanks for all explanation. I want check if a LTL A is contradictory to LTL B. For do this I transform the LTL A into a buchi automata  ( this will be my program in PROMELA) and check this program against the LTL B. If some counter-example is show it is because those LTLs are contraditory.

Comment: @Georgia wouldn't it be easier if you simply checked whether the **conjunction** of the two *LTL formulas* **is** the **empty** automaton, aka *never { false }*?

Comment: can I do this in the Spin Model Checker? Could you tell me how? At first I do not have the model that these TLs will be validated only have the LTLs.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot. You know some article that proves it? I mean, prove that the automata of two contradictory LTLs are empty?

Comment: @Georgia I don't recall any particular article stating it, although it's likely the case that if you look for the papers in which *Buchi Automatons* or *Kripke Structures* are defined you might find something. To clarify a bit your starting ideas, I advice you to read [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~emc/15-398/lectures/spin-3.ppt). Notice that when I say *empty* I truly mean that the intersection is *empty* in terms of *accepting executions*, that is *there are no paths that intersect an accepting state infinitely many times*, though there might be some state if no simplification is applied.

Comment: **LTL2BA** applies simplification, and that is the reason why in the example above we obtain a much nicer *never { false }* instead of the code presented by **Spin**, although the two automatons are *"equivalent"* *(n.b. my version of spin requires G instead of [] and F instead of <> to work properly)*. Here the problem is whether or not **LTL2BA** simplification is good enough to simplify all *empty* automatons to their *canonical form*, or not. On this regard, I can not help you.

Comment: Thanks for all explanation Patrick. I will read your reading suggestions, but you already clarify a lot my doubts.