# LTL model checking with SPIN

Tags: logic, formal-verification, model-checking, spin, promela

I am looking at the SPIN software. I would like to do use it to find models of LTL theories. All the manuals and tutorials talk about verifying properties of algorithms, but I am not interested in that at all. I simply want to find a models of LTL formulas (a corresponding Büchi automaton, I suppose), much like the mace4 or paradox model checkers can find models of FOL formulas. I  believe that SPIN should be able to do that, but I am unable to find how in the documentation. Could somebody point to any helpful resources?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. But if you want to generate a Buchi automaton from an ltl formula you can use [this](http://www.lsv.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php)

Comment: Thanks, this is very much what I was looking for.

Comment: This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780330/how-to-transform-ltl-into-automato-in-promela-spin) might be somewhat related to your needs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate a Buchi automaton from an *LTL* formula you can use the [**ltl2ba**](http://www.lsv.fr/~gastin/ltl2ba/index.php) tool. The tool can provide a *graphical* representation of the Buchi automaton or a *Promela* code version of it, as in the following example:

```
~$ ./ltl2ba -f "([] q0) && (<> ! q0)"
never {    /* ([] q0) && (<> ! q0) */
T0_init:
    false;
}
```

---

You may also use **Spin** to generate the *Promela* version of the Buchi Automaton, with the command:

```
~$ spin -f "LTL_FORMULA"
```

**e.g.:**

```
~$ spin -f "[] (q1 -> ! q0)" 
never  {    /* [] (q1 -> ! q0) */
accept_init:
T0_init:
    do
    :: (((! ((q0))) || (! ((q1))))) -> goto T0_init
    od;
}
```

However, in contrast with **ltl2ba**, **Spin** does not seem to simplify the Buchi Automaton when generating the source code, making sometimes difficult to interpret its output; **e.g.** try running `spin -f "([] q0) && (<> ! q0)"` and compare the output automaton to that obtained with **ltl2ba**.

---

**EDIT**

You can now use [**gltl2ba**](https://github.com/PatrickTrentin88/gltl2ba) in sostitution for **ltl2ba**'s website, e.g.:

```
~$ gltl2ba.py -f "([] p0) || (<> p1)" -g

never { /* ([] p0) || (<> p1) */
T0_init:
    if
    :: (1) -> goto T0_S1
    :: (p1) -> goto accept_all
    :: (p0) -> goto accept_S2
    fi;
T0_S1:
    if
    :: (1) -> goto T0_S1
    :: (p1) -> goto accept_all
    fi;
accept_S2:
    if
    :: (p0) -> goto accept_S2
    fi;
accept_all:
    skip
}
```

generates the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to convert the output to a DOT/PNG graph as in the online tool? Can the output of `ltl2ba -d` be changed to DOT somehow?

Comment: @user1747134 the easiest and most reliable way for doing this, in my opinion, is to to write a simple parser/script for the *Promela* code that is generated. The output obtained with `-d` does not seem to be complete, e.g. it does not explicitly state whether the *init* state is accepting or not.